# Synchronize two databases primary keys without atomicity

Tags: database, algorithm

Consider two databases A and B, with rows with a common primary key (PK). Both databases can only be queried by the function `return all keys of items [X,Y[`. The keys are non-sequential, and thus this query could return, e.g.

```
>>> get_Akeys(0, 5)
>>> [20, 21, 23, 24, 25]
>>> get_Bkeys(0, 5)
>>> [20, 21, 23, 24, 25]
```

With time, database A changes (B does not): it has rows **added** (always with incremental PK) and rows **deleted** (any valid PK). The aim is to keep database B synchronised with A. To that, one would add to database B the rows `A - B` (set subtraction), and delete the rows `B - A`.

Unfortunately, we don't have access to the full database A: queries of the form `get_Akeys(0, 10**10)` are forbidden because |A| is too large. Thus, a strategy is to chop it, e.g. `getA(i) = get_Akeys(i*N, (i + 1)*N)` where N is a constant, and query it sequentially.

However, this breaks atomicity of the request: consider `A = [20,21,22,25,26,27,28]` and `B = [20,21,22,25,26,27]` with `N = 3` and this sequence of events:

1. `getA(0) == [20,21,22] == getB(0)` (all correct)
2. `A.delete_key(22) # getA(0) becomes [20,21,25]`
3. `getA(1) == [26,27,28] != [25,26,27] == getB(1)`

In 3., the result would imply that the element 25 should be deleted from B (wrong), and element 28 should be added (correct).

Any ideas on how to synchronise two databases with the above constraints?

In my use case, each `getA` takes ~1 minute for the N I'm using, getting all entries requires ~100 queries for the N/|A| I'm using, and the sync can take 2 days to complete.

Comment: This is why RDBMS have replication/mirroring https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql or even INSERT and DELETE triggers http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of limiting `getA()` to returning at most a fixed *number* of keys, just limit it to returning the set of keys *within a specific range*.  Then you can never get `# getA(0) becomes [20,21,25]` occurring: after `A.delete_key(22)` runs, `getA(0) = [20,21]`.  25 still belongs to the next set.

According to your definitions ("return all keys of items [X,Y[", "getA(i) = get_Akeys(i*N, (i + 1)*N"), that's what you must be doing anyway, so I'm confused as to what the problem is.

Comment: in-order to gain more deterministic results, i would suggest: query `A` for `N` elements, then but query `B` for the range of ID's in the `A`  as j_random_hacker suggest.

Comment: @TomerW: I think this will sometimes forget to communicate deletions from A to B: Suppose we ask for the first 1000 elements from A, then update B to match, then `A.delete_key(42)` is called.  If we now ask for the second 1000 elements from A (in order to continue bringing B up to date), neither this query nor any future one will find the 1001th key in A, so if it's not already in B then B will be forever out of date.  EDIT: Or maybe that's not what you're suggesting?

Comment: I cannot do the query you are suggesting; database A is external to me, and what I wrote in the question is the only query I can do; specifically, I access db A via a GET, and the GET only has parameters `items=[a,b]` that I encapsulated in `get_Akeys` to simplicity here.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: I see now that `X` and `Y` are positional *indices* of rows, not key *values*.  (Your first code snippet suggests the right interpretation, but it would help to be more explicit.)  Do you have a means to detect when deletions to A are performed?  If you do, it would be sufficient to always start your queries to A nDeletionsSoFar rows earlier than a simple linear scan; if not, I think there's no general, efficient solution.